# How to get full name from domain name

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-10, command-prompt

So a while back, I managed to make a bat file that would let me enter in somone's username.
Then, it would search the domain for the full name and I could use that for other work. The bat I used would spit out JUST the fullname and put it in a variable.I know I can use the  `net user /domain $username` command, but that doesn't let you single out a result, as far as I'm aware

Unfortunately, I lost it and I can even fine the tutorial I used to help me with it. Does anyone know how this might be done? I did it a few years back on a windows 7 machine, I'm not sure if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is a much better option for pulling AD info and exporting it. Using the PS AD Module you could do something similar to `Get-ADUser -filter $username -properties Name | Select-Object Name` From here you could store this info in a variable or write it to a file etc. I will also link to the AD Module documentation for reference on [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser)

Comment: Gave it a shot but got an error:
`Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Filter'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that
is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:20
+ Get-ADUser -filter $username -properties Name | Select-Object Name
+                    ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser`

Comment: `-Filter` should be a string that.. wel, **Filters** for some attribute being equal or like or notlike something. Also, Get-ADUser returns property `Name` by default.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `$username` is the SamAccountName for the user, just do PowerShell:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -Properties DisplayName
```

You now have an **object** with these user properties: `DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName, DisplayName`

<sup>Only `DisplayName` needs to be asked for, all other properties are returned by default using Get-ADUser</sup>

So if you want just the DisplayName ('FullName' as you call it), just return that:

```
$fullName = (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm actually not sure how to use this, though I'm used to command-prompt.

I'm assuming I have to put the domain name in here, and then it gives me the full name. I don't know where to put it, though.

Comment: @ChristopherMccullough just copy/paste in a powershell console and run it. Make sure your variable `$username` has a valid SamAccountName in it.

Comment: I may be in a bit over my head.
I ran the first command in PowerShell, This one:
`$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -Properties DisplayName`



When I do, I get an error:

`Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:1 char:9
+ $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -Properti ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser`

Comment: @ChristopherMccullough Looks like you forgot to `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` first.. What exactly is in your variable `$username` ? Is that not the users accountname?